# regex - shorter way for multiple replace

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var str = "~lorem ~lorem1 ~ipsum ~ipsum2 ~dolor ~dolor3";
str = str.replace(/~lorem/g, 'a');
str = str.replace(/~ipsum/g, 'b');
str = str.replace(/~dolor/g, 'c');
console.log(str);  // a a1 b b2 c c3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How to execute all `str.replace` at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object and build a regular expression from the keys.

To replace with the values, you need a function which take the found string and gets the value from the object.

If the strings contains special characters, you need to escape them as well.

```js
var str = "~lorem ~lorem1 ~ipsum ~ipsum2 ~dolor ~dolor3",
    values = { '~lorem': 'a', '~ipsum': 'b', '~dolor': 'c' };

str = str.replace(new RegExp(Object.keys(values).join('|'), 'g'), k => values[k]);

console.log(str);  // a a1 b b2 c c3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine you regex like this:

`/(~lorem)|(~ipsum)|(~dolor)/g`

then you need to use a `function` as the second parameter to `replace` to set 'a','b', and 'c' as the replacement for the found text